# How can I get the audio from iOS "Classic>Alert" onto my computer?

Tags: macos, ios, audio

How  can I extract this alert sound under "Classic>Alert" from my iOS device to a sound file on my Mac so I can edit it.

(iOS 9.2, macOS 10.11.2)

The microphone on my Mac is broken, so simply recording the sound will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not an audio file, but a movie file with the audio can be made using Quicktime Player. Open the app, and select "new movie recording" under File menu. From the dropdown beside the record button, choose "iPhone" for "microphone". Then play the sound on iPhone.

You'll get a .mov file and you might need further video editing softwares to extract the sound.

This might not be the best answer for the said versions of iOS etc.

Answer (score -3):

@Tetsujin:

> It's already on the Mac, Alerts are in
>   `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Al‌​ertTones/`